# Troubleshooting Java GUI app that stopped working

Tags: mac, java, ui

I have a Java app that I use on a regular basis that has stopped launching. The application is a Java program with a Mac GUI tied to it. I suspect that with a recent upgrade of Java on the Mac platform has caused the app to stop launching. I tried stepping back a version of Java installed on the system with no luck.

How can I troubleshoot what is causing the Java program to stop launching? 
If troubleshooting doesn't work out, what steps do I need to take to try and use the program for the terminal?

Some background info, Java installed was the most recent. Then I backtracked to Java SE 7 Update 80. At least tried to. This is on a Mac with OS X 10.9.5 installed. The Java App is [MusicMount](http://odysseus.de/musicmount/2014/05/02/graphical-user-interface/)

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what the Java application is called?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan MusicMount

Comment: This MusicMount? https://github.com/beckchr/musicmount Not a good sign that the code hasn't been touched in three years and the http://musicmount.org/ website appears to have disappeared about the [same time](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://musicmount.org/).

Comment: Yes, that's it. http://odysseus.de/musicmount/ is the more recent site. But as you said it hasn't been updated. The corresponding iOS app was updated last month. Otherwise not much has been updated.

Comment: I know this doesn't help but it starts up okay on the first attempt on 10.12.5  with Java version 1.8.0_101.

Comment: That's interesting, wonder what is causing it to crash on my machine.